# Ctrl+Click shortcut not working in Maven project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, eclipse-kepler

I imported a Maven project in Eclipse Kepler, the code was compiled without any errors but now I need to navigate it but the Ctrl+Click shortcut is not working anywhere in the project. I have other Android projects in the workspace and the shortcut(Ctrl+Click) is working fine on them. I've closed all the unrelated projects but still no use. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your project must be missing the `JAVA` nature.

Usually happens when you have a parent project and multiple children.
Once you checked out the parent.

1- If children don't have `.project` and `.classpath` files go to the parent folder and `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

2- Delete the `.project` file at the root of the parent folder.

3- Import > Existing project ...
   Go in the parent project directory
   Children projects should appear, import them and they'll normally have the Java nature

If you're too slow importing, Eclipse may recreate the parent `.project` file.

Comment: I think you are right, but my children are not being recognized as separate projects themselves by Eclipse. So I can't do this.

Comment: Did you do an eclipse:eclipse on them so it would create the appropriates .project files ?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make it happen. It's not an issue now. Thanks